# Easy to set DTC

Tags: testing, android-bluetooth, can-bus

I am working with vehicle diagnostics and CAN, but have run into a problem when trying to do testing. There is nothing wrong with the vehicle I am using. I need to find either a harmless and very likely easily reversible problem I can create on the vehicle that will set a trouble code for me to read, or I need to find a way to artificially set one. I am actually not even sure the latter is possible. I know there are plenty of things I can do to cause trouble with a vehicle, but I am trying to find something that won't permanently damage the vehicle.

I know Trouble codes aren't universal across all vehicles, or at least not all of them are, I just figured that there must be some common problem that most vehicles will set a DTC for.

Comment: Important Information. The vehicle is fully electric.

Comment: You could unplug the MAF (Mass Air Flow) if your car has one and start the car. This will cause the car to enter limp mode and run using more fuel than needed. It is reversible by plugging the MAF back in and erasing the error code.